# support vector machine for the image recognition with the scikit-py digit data set

Tags: python, svm

**context**

I want to follow [this](https://youtu.be/KTeVOb8gaD4?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDd0flgGphKCej-9jp-QdzZ3) tutorial on machine learning in Python using Wakari.

At 12 minutes into the video I received an error:

**code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

digits = datasets.load_digits()
clf=svm.SVC(gamma-0.001, c-100)

print(len(digits.data))

x, y = digits.data[:1], digits.target[:-1]
clf.fit(x,y)

print('Prediction:',clf.predict(digits.data[-1]))
plt.imshow(digits.images[-1], cmap=plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation="nearest")
plt.show()
```

**error text**

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8cd67aede6c5> in <module>()
      6 
      7 digits = datasets.load_digits()
----> 8 clf=svm.SVC(gamma-0.001, c-100)
      9 
     10 print(len(digits.data))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'
```

**questions**

- why did I get that error?
- how do I get around it?

Thanks

Comment: Change `-` to `=`: `svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, c=100)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
clf=svm.SVC(gamma-0.001, c-100)
```

to

```
clf=svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100)
```

You are getting this error because in this case `gamma` seems to be a function and you are trying to substract 0.001 from it, which obviously is not possible. I'm assuming you wanted to supply parameters for your SVC, which has both parameters `gamma` and `C`